# Trying to get results to show on table with PDO Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PDO trying to figure how to get this to work with PDO. I have it working with MYSQL I maybe confused how PDO works. I am getting a blank page any ideas on how I can go about getting all the results of received records. I see tutorials on PDO but when I do it it is for single records with an array.

```
<?php
require_once("../db_connect.php");

$stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received'");
echo"Received Requests";
echo "<br><br>";

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo("<table  bgcolor=F2F2F2 width=1080 border='2'>");

echo("<br><tr><th>Id</th><th>Update</th><th>LanID</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Manager</th><th>request</th><th>Description</th><th>request_comments</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th><th>Completed User</th><th>Completed Date</th></tr>");

echo("<tr>");
echo  "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>"
."<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>"
."<td>" .  $row['lanId'] . "</td> "
. "<td>".  $row['name'] . "</td>"
. "<td>". $row['department'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['manager'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_description'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['status'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compUser'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compDt'] ."</td>";

echo '</tr>';

}
echo("</table>");

?>

<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
<title>

</title>
</head>
<body background="../images/background.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

db_connect.php

```html
<?php


$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "systems_requests";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
?>
```

Comment: Getting any errors? I'd like to see your db_connect file, also.

Comment: Is the `PDO` extension installed/enabled? Have you done any debugging? What is in your error log?

Comment: Put the first table tag outside the while loop.Also you are missing execute after prepare

Comment: First, `var_dump($row); die();` to check, is there any row in your `$stmt.`  Second, why do you echoes your table befor you start the HTML and body? You need to do this table inside `<body>` and `</body>`. 3rd, move the table outside of your loop.

Comment: I need each record to have its own table that's why I put the while loop above the table. I will try to move the table to the body. I did it this way because a lot of tutorials are still showing the old way with mysql. I will try the example bellow and see how I can get it to work. I am bit confused but i will try it out and report back any errors.

Comment: Then put the closing table tag inside the while loop.

Comment: Thank you I moved the table into the while loop did not realize it was outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to execute your prepared statement.

Please use `$stmt->execute ()` before using `$stmt->fetch ()`

Also please fetch like so:

```
$requests = $stmt->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($requests as $request) {

    echo $request["whateverKeyYouWant"];

}
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work with adding $stmt->execute (); before the fetch

Comment: The only thing is the  way i have the table written is that a correct way to do it will it be safe from sql injections. Can anyone provide an example of the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Donny [here is a link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to the correct way of adding parameters to queries, good to see it's working now. Happy coding! :)

Comment: [Here you go](https://gist.github.com/bobdesaunois/fb8031b8c0f2a99b9826) I made a gist just for you.

Comment: Thank you i looked through I think I am understanding it now. Only thing I was wondering will the results go into a table with that way> i needed to keep each record results in its own table

Comment: I believe [this is what you mean](https://gist.github.com/bobdesaunois/3acaeaf4a2de9974c783)